# How to define elements in xsd as mandatory/optional and any order

Tags: xml, xsd

I am unable to define the elements with `<xsd:all>` for below requirement,

I am getting error that `maxOccursv should be 0 or 1 under schema`all`.

Below is my requirement, could anyone please help me as soon as possible.

1. elements (`A` & `B`) can come in any order in xml (so i am using `xsd:all`, but gettting error), i don't want to go with sequence.
2. element `A` is mandatory, it should appear in xml always, however element `B` is optional.
3. element `A` & `B` can appear any number of times for example I can have element `A` 10 times and element `B` 20 times.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="InvoiceData">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="A" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1 you can use xs:all with maxOccurs values other than 0 or 1.

In XSD 1.0 the nearest you can get is the model (A|B)*, but you can't then impose different maxOccurs values for A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dr. Kay said, you can't use `<xsd:all>` for such problem in XSD 1.0. Instead, you need to modify your answer to use sequences and choices.

This XSD 1.0 code should match your three requirements: order is free, `<A>` is mandatory and maximum occurences are both unbounded.

```
<xsd:element name="InvoiceData" >
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="B" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="A"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="A"/>
                <xsd:element name="B"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a mix of A and B elements; A must occur at least once, B need not appear at all; neither has a maximum.  (If Michael Kay is right to think you do want to impose maximum occurrence counts on A and B, then things get more complicated.)

In DTD notation, `(a*, (b, a*)+)` does the trick.  In XSD notation:

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element ref="A" 
               minOccurs="0" 
               maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:element ref="B"/> 
    <xsd:element ref="A" 
                 minOccurs="0" 
                 maxOccur="unbounded"/>
  </
</
```